# What to add in part of youtube API in iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube

URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=.....................&autoLevels=true&notifySubscribers=false&stabilize=false&fields=fileDetails&key=

Where can I get **part information**?

Comment: -1 and voted to close as this lacks any research or effort of trying to solve by themselves. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the API is your friend. See here: [Understanding the part parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#part)